# How to do custom ranking of documents in solr at index time

Tags: solr, search-engine, ranking

I have to do custom ranking of few documents and I have come to know many informations from web but (as I am new) If I want to do custom ranking at index time, what parameters I should change and in which file. I think these changes will be permanet so there will be some file where I have to change it. I may be wrong. PLease guide me thoroughly. From offical website, I have found many informations like tf,idf etc. But how and where I should do these changes.

Please guide me with some example?

Comment: Your question is very generic. Maybe give an example or two of what you need to achieve.

Comment: I have some file and  when I do its indexing, those docs are not at top of search. I want to do change ranking at index time so that those docs will be at top when searched